Gradle task not copying all files from runtimeClasspath, despite a debug println of the runtimeClasspath.get().files showing all files
I have a gradle task designed to package all of my dependancies into a distribution folder:
tasks.register<Copy>("dist") {
    dependsOn("jar")
    // log the files we are about to copy
    println("copyDependencies:\n  ${project.configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().files.joinToString("\n  ") { it.absolutePath }}\n  ->\n  $buildDir/dist")
    from(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    from(tasks.jar)
    into("build/dist")
}

I'm printing the list of files that have been detected as dependencies during the build, and I correctly see 6 files, I then immediately check the content of that directory in the same shell, and the .zip file hasn't been copied, why?
PS C:\WindowsRepos\java> gradle.bat dist
copyDependencies:
  C:\WindowsRepos\java\ATE\Common\jar\ieee488.jar
  C:\WindowsRepos\java\ATE\Common\jar\oncrpc.jar
  C:\WindowsRepos\java\ATE\Common\jar\swing-worker-1.2.jar
  C:\WindowsRepos\java\Utils\build\libs\caUtils.jar
  C:\WindowsRepos\java\SerialioImporter\build\libs\Serialio.jar
  C:\WindowsRepos\java\SerialioImporter\SerialioImporter\ext\Serialio Shared Libs.zip
  ->
  C:\WindowsRepos\java\ATE\Common\build/dist

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
10 actionable tasks: 10 up-to-date
PS C:\WindowsRepos\java> dir .\ATE\Common\build\dist\


    Directory: C:\WindowsRepos\java\ATE\Common\build\dist


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        31/05/2024     17:49        1181180 caATECommon.jar
-a----        31/05/2024     17:49         311977 caUtils.jar
-a----        31/05/2024     17:49          50641 ieee488.jar
-a----        31/05/2024     17:49          87603 oncrpc.jar
-a----        31/05/2024     17:49          67119 Serialio.jar
-a----        31/05/2024     17:49          12852 swing-worker-1.2.jar

There were no errors reported, the entire build output was included, I've tried adding --info and --debug to the gradle call, and there don't seem to be any logs about copying the files that I can discern.
I asked co-pilot for help and it suggested that zip filer were a special case, and that I needed to adjust my task:
    from(configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().files.filter { !it.name.endsWith(".zip") })
    from(configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().files.filter { it.name.endsWith(".zip") }.map { it.absolutePath })

But that didn't help. I'm at a complete loss, why won't it copy this file?

EDITS

Can copy the file manually (not a permissions issue AFAIK)
Added a doLast block with the println to verify the .zip isn't being removed from the classpath


I then immediately check the content of that directory in the same shell, and the .zip file has gone hasn't been copied, why? Because it has a space in the path?

If the space is the problem, then I can't reproduce it with Gradle 8.8.

@Slaw did you use Powershell?

@g00se I did, but I don't believe that matters. The copying is being handled by Gradle, not the shell.

I think there is a strange bug here because I agree: I expect the files in your println to be the same as the ones copied. One possibility is that the configuration has changed between the println and the copy; to check if this has happened, you could try putting your println inside a doLast block to see if it gives the same output, to check the state of the inputs after the copy operation.

@SimonJacobs the println was originally inside a doLast block, I even had two, one inside and one outside, they reported the same information, so I trimmed one for brevity

Could this be a permission issue? Are you able to copy the ZIP file directly with Copy-Item?

@Slaw I am able to copy the file directly

Then I'm not sure what the problem could be, as I cannot reproduce it. I created a new Gradle 8.8 project, created an empty ZIP file named foo bar.zip (in the project directory), added the ZIP file as a dependency with implementation(files("foo bar.zip")), configured a copy task like in your question, executed it, and saw the ZIP file in the destination directory.

@Slaw Don't forget to put something with nasty spaces in its path ;)

@g00se I did, in the file name just like in the OP: foo bar.zip

@g00se in my defence, I neither named the file, nor decided it was a dependancy, just trying to lug an ancient project into the modern era, it was limited to java 1.4 when I inherited it, I believe SerialIO is now defunct as there are built-in serial utilities, so this is unlikely to be an issue long term

Ah OK all - it's a mystery. I don't know if the Windows equivalent of strace exists, but could be useful if it does
